# DotNetCore 1.0.1 WindowsHosting Installation Fails for IIS Windows Server 2012R2

Tags: iis, .net-core, windows-server-2012-r2

Things I tried:

- Running admin
- Turning off UAC
- Restarting machine
- I am supposed to be admin on the machine

I have the following error log:

```
[0A48:124C][2016-09-16T13:28:19]i300: Apply begin
[0A48:124C][2016-09-16T13:28:19]i010: Launching elevated engine process.
[0A48:124C][2016-09-16T13:28:19]i011: Launched elevated engine process.
[0A48:124C][2016-09-16T13:28:20]i012: Connected to elevated engine.
[0D94:0270][2016-09-16T13:28:20]i358: Pausing automatic updates.
[0D94:0270][2016-09-16T13:28:20]i359: Paused automatic updates.
[0D94:0270][2016-09-16T13:28:20]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[0D94:0270][2016-09-16T13:28:20]i362: System restore disabled, system restore point not created.
[0D94:0270][2016-09-16T13:28:20]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{e39e00c9-09be-48bb-b175-01a07b3f7538}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[0D94:08CC][2016-09-16T13:28:20]i304: Verified existing payload: AspNetCoreModule_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{4ADC4F4A-2D55-442A-8655-FBF619F94A69}v1.0.1967\packages\aspnetcoremodule_x64_en_rc2_39.msi.
[0D94:0270][2016-09-16T13:28:20]i301: Applying execute package: AspNetCoreModule_x64, action: Repair, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{4ADC4F4A-2D55-442A-8655-FBF619F94A69}v1.0.1967\packages\aspnetcoremodule_x64_en_rc2_39.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7"'
[0D94:08CC][2016-09-16T13:28:20]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed to find payload: DotNetRedist_x64 in working path: C:\Users\OSCHEL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\{3C386474-F8E3-4928-8751-FBC35786E734}\DotNetRedist_x64 and unverified path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\DotNetRedist_x64
[0D94:08CC][2016-09-16T13:28:20]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed to cache payload: DotNetRedist_x64
[0A48:0A5C][2016-09-16T13:28:20]e314: Failed to cache payload: DotNetRedist_x64 from working path: C:\Users\OSCHEL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\{3C386474-F8E3-4928-8751-FBC35786E734}\DotNetRedist_x64, error: 0x80070002.
[0A48:0A5C][2016-09-16T13:28:20]e349: Application requested retry of payload: DotNetRedist_x64, encountered error: 0x80070002. Retrying...
[0D94:08CC][2016-09-16T13:28:20]i305: Verified acquired payload: DotNetRedist_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\DotNetRedist_x64, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\21CBEEE3E1DCAA0BD8F9DA42A6230CF52F9F5A78\packages\DotNetCore.1.0.1-Runtime-x64.exe.
[0A48:124C][2016-09-16T13:28:21]i319: Applied execute package: AspNetCoreModule_x64, result: 0x0, restart: None
[0D94:0270][2016-09-16T13:28:21]i325: Registering dependency: {e39e00c9-09be-48bb-b175-01a07b3f7538} on package provider: IIS_AspNetCore_Module,x64, package: AspNetCoreModule_x64
[0D94:0270][2016-09-16T13:28:21]i301: Applying execute package: DotNetRedist_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\21CBEEE3E1DCAA0BD8F9DA42A6230CF52F9F5A78\packages\DotNetCore.1.0.1-Runtime-x64.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\21CBEEE3E1DCAA0BD8F9DA42A6230CF52F9F5A78\packages\DotNetCore.1.0.1-Runtime-x64.exe" /quiet /norestart'
[0D94:0270][2016-09-16T13:28:30]e000: Error 0x80070490: Process returned error: 0x490
[0D94:0270][2016-09-16T13:28:30]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to execute EXE package.
[0A48:124C][2016-09-16T13:28:30]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[0A48:124C][2016-09-16T13:28:30]i319: Applied execute package: DotNetRedist_x64, result: 0x80070490, restart: None
[0A48:124C][2016-09-16T13:28:30]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to execute EXE package.
[0D94:0270][2016-09-16T13:28:30]i351: Removing cached package: DotNetRedist_x64, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\21CBEEE3E1DCAA0BD8F9DA42A6230CF52F9F5A78\
[0D94:0270][2016-09-16T13:28:30]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{e39e00c9-09be-48bb-b175-01a07b3f7538}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
[0D94:0270][2016-09-16T13:28:30]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{e39e00c9-09be-48bb-b175-01a07b3f7538}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[0A48:124C][2016-09-16T13:28:31]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070490, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by installing this package http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615460&clcid=0x409

The logs from the DotNetCore.1.0.1-WindowsHosting installation weren't very helpful, so I tried to install the DotNetCore.1.0.1-SDK.1.0.0.Preview2-003131-x64 package which also failed. However, the SDK Preview 2 logs had more information and it showed that it failed due to a problem acquiring this package.

> **ERROR from log:** Acquiring package: VC_redist.x64.exe, payload: VC_redist.x64.exe, download from: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615460&clcid=0x409

After manually downloading and installing this package I was able to install both Windows Hosting and SDK Preview 2 on my server.

Comment: Dispite I got no error with the fix mentioned by @Ignas. It seemed dotnet Core runtime was not installed. After installing the package from your link, it worked for me!

Comment: Thank you Paulo, your solution worked for me on Windows 2008 R2 as well.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks so much!

Comment: I installed it ,but it is also shows error as higher version is already installed in my server,and still .net core is not intalling

Answer (score 3):

From [.NET Framework Downloads](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download#winserverhost) page:

> You can download the Windows (Server Hosting) installer and run the following command from an Administrator command prompt:
>
> `DotNetCore.1.0.1-WindowsHosting.exe OPT_INSTALL_REDIST=0`